# REPLACE INTO MySQL / Update instead of INSERT when record existing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just performed 3x the following SQL:

```
REPLACE INTO `admin_gerschap`.`prices` (`ean`, `shopID`, `price`, `shipmentCost`, `productURL`) VALUES ('12', '1', '3', '11', '5')
```

This shouldn't create 3 records, right? But it created 3x the same record.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a unique field set? Replace into needs some reference to a field that should only occur once

Comment: No, I don't have it. Field ean+shopID together is always unique.

Comment: That statement is confusing. ean + shopID may always be unique but unless you mark the ean field as unique the system doesn't know about it. If you use phpmyadmin, click on the prices table, click structure, then click the "U" icon for the ean field. It will add a unique index to that field and replace into should work

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant (ean+shopID) together is unique, not just ean or shopID. So can I make an unique field out of 2 fields?

Comment: you can select both in the structure view and click unique at the bottom. That can group the request. You will have to verify that it actually applies it to both together. I've never tried to unique 2 things together though.

Comment: You can have a compound unique key. However, it should be PRIMARY, not UNIQUE if that is what is being searched. A table without a Primary Key is 99% of the time a bad idea.